# Why is my dynamodb throughput so high?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, amazon-dynamodb, throughput

I have a python script that reads JSON messages from a queue and batct-writes these messages into DynamoDB table. Each message has a primary ID and a secondary ID and I use a table with a GSI to index the messages.

So I am assuming that I am writing one DynamoDB item per one JSON message received from the queue. Here's a simplified version of the code (I am using `dynamodb2`)

```
i = 0
with table.batch_write() as batch:
    while True:
         m = inq.read()
         i = i + 1
         mStr = json.dumps(m)
         pid = m['primaryId']
         sid = m['secondaryId']
         item_data = {"primaryId" : pid, "secondaryId"] : sid, "message"] : mStr}
         batch.put_item(data=item_data)

         if i == 25:
             batch.resend_unprocessed()
             i = 0
```

Here is the block that creates the table

```
table = Table.create(   tName,
            schema=[HashKey('primaryId')],
            throughput={    'read': 5,
                    'write': 1000},
            global_indexes=[
                GlobalAllIndex('secIdIndex',
                        parts=[HashKey('secondaryId')],
                        throughput={
                            'read': 5,
                            'write': 1000})],
            connection=conn)
```

An important caveat: using the `multiprocessing` library, I launch 10 identical copies of the writer script. Each copy of the script reads from the same queue, and they all write into the same table simultaneously. This is done in order to keep up with the amount of data flowing through the input queue, since I also have to process each message before I write that message in its original form into the table. I do not include the processing part of the script here since it's irrelevant.

I collected some stats and it looks like I receive about **150** JSON messages per second through the input queue. Each of the 10 writer workers grabs about 1/10th of that and so each of them writes approximately 15 messages per second into the DynamoDB table. So I would expect that my provisioned write throughput should be about 150. However, currently it stands at **1000** because the AWS monitoring shows that this is what my actual throughput is at times. It shows lower values at other times but this never goes below several hundred.

Why such a huge discrepancy? How should I calculate the throughput I need from the amount of data/number of items I try to write into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was not calculating the required throughput correctly: it's not just based on the number of written items but on their sizes. A single write unit per second is for 1Kb of data. So an item that's 2Kb in size requires twice the throughput of an 1Kb item. Most of my items are a lot bigger than 1Kb.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a table with:

- Hash key: it is the main index, which defines the partition of the table.
- Global index: which is only useful if you want to search by this index, apart form the hash. This implies a lot of resource consumption.

I think you want to query either by only hash or by only global index. Is this correct?

Do you really want a global Index?

Can it be that you want to query either by hash or by hash+range?

Comment: Yes, I need to be able to retrieve my messages either by `primaryId` or by `secondaryId`. That was the whole reason for switching from `dynamodb` to `dynamodb2`. I have an older version of this code that uses `dynamodb` and a simple hash-key index. That is working fine but is not insufficient for my purposes. The value of 1000 is provisioned throughput on the primary index, not on primary+GSI.